# How do I update a tag in an XML file in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

How can I update the value of tags in an XML file using System.Xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update values in the file directly.

You load the file into an XmlDocument object, manipulate the nodes in the object, then save the document back to the same file.